# C# WPF: How do I Bind the content of a label to a value inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to be able to bind fc:ColorSlider to a value in my MainWindow.XAML
The following code is my ColorSlider.XAML

I want to bind the Text Content to my RedSlider or RGB Sliders. Normally this would be easy but my sliders are in a UserControl and my Textbox is in my MainWindow.

```
 <Rectangle Width="165" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" Stroke="Black">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RgbConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="RedSlider"/>
                            <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="GreenSlider"/>
                            <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="BlueSlider"/>
                            <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="AlphaSlider"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                        <!-- Describes the brush's color using
                              RGB values. Each value has a range of 0-255.  -->
                        <!--<Color A="255" R="255" G="0" B="0" />-->
                    </SolidColorBrush.Color>
                </SolidColorBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
```

This code is my MainWindow.XAML

```
<fc:ColorSlider Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  x:Name="ColorSlider">     </fc:ColorSlider>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="250" Height="Auto" Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0,2,0"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="250" Text="{Binding ElementName=ColorSlider, Path=RedSlider, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Width="250" Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Width="250" Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>


    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="250" Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="250" Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="250" Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="250" Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>

    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">Display Preview With Sliders?</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property in the code behind of your user control. Bind your control slider value to that property.

You should be able to bind to it from your main window also.